# Issue to have ellipses in multiple lines using angular 7

Tags: css, angular, angular6, angular7

I am trying to show ellipses in multi-line block in Angular. But facing below issue.

component.html

```
<div class="test" [innerHtml]="anchor1.length >= 200 ? anchor1.substring(0,242) + '...' : anchor"></div>
```

component.ts

```
anchor1 = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id nam probo vidisse feugait.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, id nam probo vidisse feugait. Liber invenire expetendis eu duo, constituto assueverit ex mei. Mea ea quot mundi. <a href="abcdefghi.com">Test</a> <a href="#">test 2</a>';
```

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ksgxdj

The expected output in should be "Test..." but I am getting it as "Test" at the end of line.

since I have this scenario where anchor can be anywhere, I have simulated the scenario using substring and hard coded values.

Here Angular is rendering

```
Lorem ipsum dolor etc etc <a href="abcdefghi.com">Test</a> <a href="#"...
```

Which gets truncated to

```
Lorem ipsum dolor etc etc <a href="abcdefghi.com">Test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the `ng-truncate` library to achieve this, why reinvent the wheel.
https://github.com/yellowspot/ng2-truncate

Example:

Import it into your module

```
import { TruncateModule } from "@yellowspot/ng-truncate";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ...
  ],
  imports: [
     TruncateModule,
  ]
});
```

In your view you can do

```
<div class="test" [innerHtml]="anchor | truncate:200"></div>
```

Comment: Good one, but it won't work this scenario. It will end up in same issue. I have checked it's truncate pipe code... very similar to my code

value.length > limit ? trail + value.substring(value.length - limit, value.length) : value;

Answer (score -1):

You can truncate text like this (using slice pipe)

```
{{ (str.length>6)? (str | slice:0:6)+'..':(str) }}
```

Comment: The issue is different .. truncation is already there but facing issue when there is anchor tag. Please check the example in question